# wordpress customizr theme editing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a home page with feature page functionality. I set a detail page with one of feature page link. and put a image in detail page so I can see it in home page's feature page link. I want to hide that image when display a detail page. Image is just for home page should not visible in detail page. is there any way to do this

Comment: Try wordpress.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image you need on front page as "featured image" of the page (in the right sidebar of the page edit screen). And that should do the trick. Hope this helps

More about front page design in Customizr : http://www.themesandco.com/customizr/#homepage